# Denormalizing to speed up inserts

Tags: mysql, innodb, denormalization

I have a MySQL InnoDb table with approximately 40 million rows and the following columns:

```
param1 (int), 
param2 (int), 
param3 (int), 
geo    (char2), 
value1 (bigint), 
value2 (bigint)
```

I have an index on `(param1,param2,param3,geo)`. Almost all queries against this table are of the form:

```
WHERE param1=? 
AND param2=? 
AND param3=?
AND geo=?
```

In total there are around 200 `geo` codes. So, we can reduce the number of rows by a factor of 200 by transforming the table structure to:

```
param1, param2, param3, value1, value2, US, DE, GB... `
```

This table is recreated and refilled every hour. Inserting data takes too long. I think reducing the number of rows x200 might decrease the insert time. Is it worth doing this denormalization for faster inserts?

Comment: Why are you even considering this? Are the queries slow?

Comment: Provide the following please:
show table status like 'yourTable'\G
show create table yourTable\G
Since it is InnoDB, it is important to know what is your primary key

Comment: @JehadKeriaki, I have a primary autoincrement bigint field as primary key.

Comment: @ypercube, sorry, totally forgot. Please see UPD for my post. PS: SELECT queries are pretty fast because they're 100% using index.

Comment: So, the problem is how to `INSERT` faster?

Comment: @ypercube, yes, exatly. Right now I'm inserting by chunks and not satisfied with speed :(

Comment: How are you currently doing the INSERTs (which software)?

Comment: If there are many indexes, or big indexes, then the insert will be slow. Depending on your data distribution, you may be able to reduce the size of the index that involves 4 fields (Internally it is 5 fields, 22 bytes! )

Comment: or you can LOAD DATA INFILE. It will be faster

Comment: @JoshuaHuber, I'm inserting from PHP using MySQL PDO. Inserting step by step using 50K-250K data chunks (I can't increase chunk size because of some application restrictions).

Comment: @akuzminsky, thank you for your comment. Will `LOAD DATA INFILE` work with remote DB connection?

Comment: Kirzilla, you have two options: 1) upload a file to remote MySQL server or 2) keep the file on a client and use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`